Can thecontentslabel text values be right justified in a table of contents?
Would you please tell me if it is possible (and, if so, how) to right align the Roman numerals in the first column of the table of contents?
No positioning options seem to have any effect in [\footnotesize\Rom{\thecontentslabel}.].
I'm very new to using LaTeX but it appears that thecontentslabel and contentslabel aren't really separate columns; but, \thecontentslabel appears to have a set width; and I'd like to know if it is possible to align the text to the right within that allotted width.
Thank you.
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass[b5paper,12pt,openright,twoside,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{yfonts}  % Needed for Roman numerals.

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother
\raggedbottom

\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\titlecontents{chapter}
[5em]
{}
{\contentslabel[\footnotesize\Rom{\thecontentslabel}.]{3em}}
{}
{\scshape\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\textsf{\footnotesize \contentspage}}
[\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}]

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\makeatletter
% Redefine the \chapter* header macro to remove vertical space
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  %\vspace*{50\p@}% Remove the vertical space
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Large \scshape \centering #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 20\p@
  }}
\makeatother
{\scshape \tableofcontents}

\contentsline{chapter}{\numberline{1}A-Head}{2}{}
\contentsline{chapter}{\numberline{3}B-Head}{5}{}
\contentsline{chapter}{\numberline{10}C-Head}{12}{}
\contentsline{chapter}{\numberline{14}D-Head}{40}{}
\end{document}



\usepackage{yfonts}  % Needed for Roman numerals. yfonts are unrelated to roman numerals (and you are not using the package fonts at all here

I added titletoc tag as \thecontentslabel is not a standard command, it is specific to that package.


The definition of a custom version of \Roman seems unnecessary really but simply adding \hfill will flush the text to the right.
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass[b5paper,12pt,openright,twoside,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\raggedbottom

\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\titlecontents{chapter}
[5em]
{}
{\contentslabel[\hfill\footnotesize\Rom{\thecontentslabel}.]{3em}}
{}
{\scshape\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\textsf{\footnotesize \contentspage}}
[\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}]

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\makeatletter
% Redefine the \chapter* header macro to remove vertical space
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  %\vspace*{50\p@}% Remove the vertical space
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Large \scshape \centering #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 20\p@
  }}
\makeatother
{\scshape \tableofcontents}

\contentsline{chapter}{\numberline{1}A-Head}{2}{}
\contentsline{chapter}{\numberline{3}B-Head}{5}{}
\contentsline{chapter}{\numberline{10}C-Head}{12}{}
\contentsline{chapter}{\numberline{14}D-Head}{40}{}
\end{document}


you might want to add a space after the .
